# LCD Controller receives command whilst busy

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

Seems like PIC is issuing command while the controller is busy in operation. here is the screen-shot
[image]

Here is the C-code for the above configuration [LCD Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16158781/lcd_code.txt)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am not using delays b/w byte transfer to LCD, instead, i used D7 bit to monitor whether the LCD is busy or not.

Comment: Is it only the simulation that doesn't work or the actual physical circuit too?

Comment: I haven't built the physical ckt yet. I am just running the simulation.

Comment: *"instead, i used D7 bit to monitor whether the LCD is busy or not."* That would be a good place to start looking for bugs.

Comment: @dannyf : I have read the code several times, still couldn't find why it is busy while receiving characters. I have modified the above code and now it shows numbers and special characters but NOT ALPHABETS. And of course, the above error message still remains. Here is the modified code 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16158781/code2.txt